# Is [:graph:] equivalent to \S in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, posix

There is a table at http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html that summarizes all the POSIX bracket expressions and also provides the equivalent shorthand.

I am unable to understand why this doesn't mention `\S` as a shorthand for `[:graph:]`. Are they different? If yes, then could you please explain me, with examples, how they are different?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[:graph:]` is different character class from `\S`.

`[:graph:]` only match visible characters. But `\S` match any characters that is not space (space, newline, character return, line feed, tab, vertical tab, ..).

For example, `[:graph:]` does not match NUL, Backspace, BEL, ..., but `\S` match them.

---

Python example using [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package (which support POSIX character classes):

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r'[[:graph:]]', 'a \0 \a \b z')
['a', 'z']
>>> regex.findall(r'\S', 'a \0 \a \b z')
['a', '\x00', '\x07', '\x08', 'z']
```